# The cross-reference boxes in TeX: the program

Tags: documentation, books, source

You know those boxes at the bottom of the right-hand pages in Volume B? Well, I managed  to weave `mf.web` by stealing the weave binary from a distribution where it actually works (it doesn't in MiKTeX), and it TeXed fine, but I'm at a bit of a loss as to why those boxes haven't appeared. Is there any way I can get them, or are does Knuth keep the code for that locked up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the "mini-index" listings in volume b were generated separately and added
in post-processing.  there is a chapter in knuth's book "digital typography"
entitled "mini-indexes for literate programs" (it's chapter 11, pp.225-245), as
well as several other entries in the index.

a program TWILL was used to create the mini-indexes in both volumes b and d.
the name was "suggested by the fact that it was a two-pass variant of the standard
program called WEAVE."  there were several references to TWILL in the course of the
panel discussion at tug 2010.  (see http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-2/tb98panel.pdf or
the video of the panel at http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/tug-2010-panel/)  apparently TWILL
is somewhere on knuth's web site (http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/), .  "It's not that easy to use, so I don't advertise it much.  It requires running in several passes."

so it *is* out there to be explored, if not that easy to use.

Comment: Hmm, looks like someone asked the same question not too long ago on TeXhax: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.texhax/13687; unfortunately I'm not seeing any sign of TWILL itself -- I hope I don't have to write a letter to Knuth and wait until he reads it in 2014 before I can learn the URL!

Comment: I've found a [SO question about CTWILL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856425/ctwill-mini-indexes-for-cweb) (answered it, too!), and a [tape listing](http://www.saildart.org/prog/SYS/html/044063?18754,1198520) that contains an entry for TWILL.WEB and one for TWILL.CH...

Comment: ... and score! here I can actually get to the files: http://www.saildart.org/prog/SYS/TEX_SYS/.browser.html